# How to find empty values while reading csv file using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am pretty new to batch file scripting.

I have to read data from the CSV file. Luckily I find a way to read.

But now struck with one more hurdle.

While reading CSV file I need to give warning for **empty** values of mandatory fields.

Given below is example of CSV file.

**Example:**

```
1,'EMPTY FIELD','abc','efg','tiger'
2, '172.16.2.22','xyz','str','lion'
```

Mandatory field is `ipaddress`. If that column is empty or null I need to give alert.

Batch file:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1-6* delims=, " %%a in ("template.csv") do (
    set sno=%%a
    set ipaddress=%%b
    set username=%%c
    set password=%%d
    set port=%%e
    set domain=%%f

    IF !ipaddress! == [] ECHO is empty

    ECHO !sno!, !ipaddress!, !username!, !password!, !port!, !domain! 
)
pause
```

To check the values is null or not I tried this:

```
IF !ipaddress! == [] ECHO is empty
```

But this IF condition is not working.

Comment: how are you reading it? You've given us an example of your file but not your current script!

Comment: Is it the literal string `EMPTY FIELD` or does the line actually look like `1,'','abc','efg','tiger'`? Or does the line look like `1,'abc','efg','tiger'`?

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SomethingDark, it actually look like 1,'','abc','efg','tiger'.

Answer (score 1):

The batch command line

```
IF !ipaddress! == [] ECHO is empty
```

compares the value of environment variable `ipaddress` with the string `[]`. Yes, the square brackets don't have a special meaning. The command **IF** on usage for string comparison always compares just what is left of `==` with what is right of `==`.

The code below is written to work for

```
1,'','abc','efg','tiger'
2, '172.16.2.22','xyz','str','lion'
```

as well as for

```
1,,abc,efg,tiger
2, 172.16.2.22,xyz,str,lion
```

The problem with `delims=,` is that command **FOR** interprets a sequence of commas as 1 delimiter. Therefore it is necessary to make sure that the row from CSV file does not contain 1 or more `,,` which is done by replacing all commas by `,#`. The inserted `#` is later removed from each non empty value.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%# in ("template.csv") do (
    set "Row=%%#"
    set "Row=!Row:, =,!"
    set "Row=!Row:,=,#!"
    for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in ("!Row!") do (
        set "sno=%%a"
        set "ipaddress=%%b"
        if "!ipaddress!" == "#" (
            echo IP address is empty in: %%#
        ) else if "!ipaddress!" == "#''" (
            echo IP address is empty in: %%#
        )
        set "ipaddress=!ipaddress:~1!"
        set "username=%%c"
        if not "!username!" == "" set "username=!username:~1!"
        set "password=%%d"
        if not "!password!" == "" set "password=!password:~1!"
        set "port=%%e"
        if not "!port!" == "" set "port=!port:~1!"
        set "domain=%%f"
        if not "!domain!" == "" set "domain=!domain:~1!"
        echo !sno!, !ipaddress!, !username!, !password!, !port!, !domain!
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to parse CSV data using a standard `for` loop to split each line. The only drawback is that the characters `*` and `?` are not allowed in the entire file. The CSV file(s) need(s) to be provided as command line argument(s):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (%*) do (
    set "FILE=%%~F"
    set /A "LIDX=0"
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%%~F") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        set /A "LIDX+=1, IIDX=0"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%I in ("!LINE:,=" "!") do (
            endlocal
            set "ITEM=%%~I"
            set /A "IIDX+=1"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if "!ITEM:~,1!"=="'" if "!ITEM:~-1!"=="'" set "ITEM=!ITEM:~1,-1!"
            if "!ITEM!"=="" (
                if !IIDX! EQU 2 (
                    >&2 echo Empty item found: file "!FILE!", row !LIDX!, column !IIDX!.
                )
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The variables `LIDX` and `IIDX` hold row and column indexes, respectively. An error message is returned here in case the second column contains an empty value.